# How to find out which Messier objects are in the Kepler/K2 fields?

Tags: observational-astronomy, kepler, messier-catalog, k2

I am interested in figuring out which Messier globular clusters (plus 47 Tuc and Omega Cen) are in the Kepler/K2 fields, both fields that have already been observed and any that will be observed.

Poking around online I was able to figure out that [Campaign 2 of K2 observed M4 and M80](https://keplerscience.arc.nasa.gov/K2/GuestInvestigationsC02.shtml), but I would like to get a complete sample of globular clusters that have fallen or will fall into the Kepler/K2 fields, especially the Kepler field.  Are there online tools that could help me figure this out?